# Importing images with CTR fails silently

Tags: kubernetes, containers, k3s, containerd

I exported docker images in .tar format.
Then importing those images using K3S and ctr showed no results :

```
$ sudo k3s ctr i import myimage.tar
$
```

No output from `import` cmd ?

```
$ sudo k3s ctr i ls
$
```

Nothing there....

Answer (score 6):

Adding `--digest=true` worked for me :

```
$ sudo k3s ctr i import myimage.tar --digests=true
unpacking import-2021-05-19@sha256:f9952729292daa8d099c7bc3275f483fdb11ffa9bb1fc394bc06b44c101047e2 (sha256:f9952729292daa8d099c7bc3275f483fdb11ffa9bb1fc394bc06b44c101047e2)...done
```

And listing images also confirms that the importation has worked :

```
$ sudo k3s ctr i ls  
...  
import-2021-05-19@sha256:f99527292fa9bb1fc394bc06b44c101047e2 application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json sha256:f9952729292dac06b44c101047e2 939.9 MiB linux/amd64 io.cri-containerd.image=managed
```

Comment: this has been changed `--digests`

Comment: it works yes, but would be nice to understand the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that in my case; I've created an image from image ID, not from tag. So when I want to import my image through `ctr`, It cannot recognize the tag. So it could not create an image.

Let having a docker image like:

```
REPOSITORY               TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
hel.lo/repopath/dev      my-image   5b40ecbbea23   3 hours ago    230MB
```

So if you save the image with the below command, `ctr` cannot create an image.

```
docker save 5b40ecbbea23 > my-image.tar
```

If you open the created tar file and look at the manifest.json file, you will see something like below(**RepoTags is null**):

```
[
  {
    "Config": "5b40ecbbea27ebdfbedabb732e228cb5649b0383ef6508257263978586cc8f9c.json",
    "RepoTags": null,
    "Layers": [...]
  }
]
```

Once you save the image via below command, it could create an image:

```
docker save hel.lo/repopath/dev:my-image > my-image.tar
```

If you open the created tar file and look at the manifest.json file, you will see something like below(RepoTags is `hel.lo/repopath/dev:my-image:my-image`):

```
[
  {
    "Config": "5b40ecbbea27ebdfbedabb732e228cb5649b0383ef6508257263978586cc8f9c.json",
    "RepoTags": [
      "hel.lo/repopath/dev:my-image:my-image"
    ],
    "Layers": [...]
  }
]
```